# How to check the test while reverting a commit and preserving the unit test?

Tags: c++, git, unit-testing, software-design

I am working with an open source project. Actually I have a clone of master and I am writing unit tests. Now after writing unit test say in abc.cxx
I want to check whether my test fails or not by reverting a commit (I have commit ID of the patch that actually fixed the bug).

So what's the best way to check this via git commands. I have tried git revert but my test was also erased(in abc.cxx) and I was unable to test the function.

I am a beginner with git and causing any sort of error can cause me a rebuild of master(6-7 hours).

Comment: Copy (not clone) your repo folder after the build, then play around with the copy. Even if you mess up, you have the original intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to:

1. commit your unit test in a dedicated, temporary branch,
2. revert the bug fix in this branch,
3. test your unit test,
4. if everything is OK, rebase/merge your unit-test on master

Demo:

```
# INIT
$ git init test
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/test/.git/
$ cd test/
$ echo bug > file
$ git add file
$ git commit -m"Commit with bugs in it"
[master (root-commit) 498680f] Commit with bugs in it
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 file
$ echo feature > file
$ git commit -am"Fix bug #1"
[master 05540d3] Fix bug #1
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)

# (1)
$ echo 42 > unit-test
$ git add unit-test
$ git checkout -b unit-test
A   unit-test
Switched to a new branch 'unit-test'
$ git commit -m"Add unit test for bug #1"
[unit-test 240bc6c] Add unit test for bug #1
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 unit-test
$ git l
* 240bc6c (HEAD, unit-test) Add unit test for bug #1
* 05540d3 (master) Fix bug #1
* 498680f Commit with bugs in it

# (2)
$ git revert 05540d3
Finished one revert.
[unit-test 5f5eb62] Revert "Fix bug #1"
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
$ git l
* 5f5eb62 (HEAD, unit-test) Revert "Fix bug #1"
* 240bc6c Add unit test for bug #1
* 05540d3 (master) Fix bug #1
* 498680f Commit with bugs in it

# (3)
$ # check for bug

# (4)
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
$ git rebase 240bc6c
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Fast-forwarded master to 240bc6c.
$ git branch -D unit-test
Deleted branch unit-test (was 5f5eb62).
$ git l
* 240bc6c (HEAD, master) Add unit test for bug #1
* 05540d3 Fix bug #1
* 498680f Commit with bugs in it
```